# PHP Header redirect and echo out session on next page?

Tags: php, mysql

i am submitting a form and then using header redirect to take the user to a new page. how can i add a session to my header redirect to say once user has been redirected echo out a div within a session saying something like form submitted?

heres what i have tried to do but can not get it to work, can someone please point me in the right direction, thanks.

submit_form.php:

```
header("Location: ../index.php?success=$success");
```

index.php:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?>
    <?php $success= "<div> CONGRATULATIONS!!!!!</DIV>"; ?>
```

Comment: you want to show success message after form submission. right?

Answer (score 0):

A session value is something stored in a session started with `session_start()`.
What you have is a URL query parameter, which you can access with `$_GET['success']`.

Answer (score 0):

submit_form.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['success'] = true;
header("Location: ../index.php?success=$success");
```

index.php:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success']) {
   //Echo your div
}
```

You appear to be mixing up `$_SESSION` and `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

On submit_form.php page:

```
 $_SESSION['success'] = "YOUR SUCCESS MESSAGE";
 header("Location: ../index.php");
```

On index.php page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success']!=""){
    echo $_SESSION['success'];
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
```

On both page, on top, put below code:

```
session_start();
```